# How to use SQL Server 2008R2 for working purpose as part of personal use

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

SQL server 2008R2 was installed on my personal laptop just for my working data, all the logins used were setup by our system admin which was connected too remotely from home. I need to use the same SQL Server for Doing some tutorials and adding my own data apart from my working data.

Is it possible to do that or do I need to install another SQL Server for my personal use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this provided that the SQL logins that you were provided contain the necessary privileges.  Some DBAs will restrict access to specific dbs or schemas, or lock down your ability to do much beyond running queries.  Assuming this is not your case you should be good to go.  Try creating a new database.  If you are successful then my guess is that they gave you a privileged account and you should be in the clear.

If you really want to be safe then I suggest obtaining a copy of [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx)

Comment: thanks, i found out that i cannot create new database...better i go for the second option:)